# Internal/external mics no longer recognized after dropping laptop

Tags: sound, microphone

I dropped my Lenovo T440s and the only thing it impacted is that my mic no longer works. What's weird is that the audio device is no longer recognized as having a mic (capture). Here's a screen shot from AlsaMixer:

[AlsaMixer shows "This device does not have any capture controls"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/getzS.png)

I could understand if somehow the internal mic was physically damaged, but plugging in an external mic -- which worked only hours before -- now also no longer works.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: in alsamixer, press F6 to select main audio device instead of HDMI audio

Comment: Yikes! That's better as far as AlasMixer is concerned. That said, Audacity isn't recording, whether I have my headphones in or not.

Comment: Or you could try testing online testing websites.

Comment: on the motherboard , it could be that the same connector connect both mic and has been damaged  : i would  look inside laptop...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. Somehow this worked itself out. Not sure if there's a loose connector or something, but all's well now.